# AuthorizeNet sdk-android issues

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am making an app in which i need to accept online payment through credit card. For this I am using AuthorizeNet sdk.

I have implemented it from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-android/tree/master/sampleapp .

The sample is working fine. But whenever i enter credit card number , It does not accept less than 16 digit number.

Whereas credit cards of type American Express having 15 digit card number `ex:370000000000002` or Visa test card number `ex:4012888818888` of 13 digit length are valid.

But this sample results null for transaction made using these credit card numbers. I am not getting why my transaction is null for credit card numbers like `370000000000002,4012888818888` but transaction is successfull for card numbers of length 16 like `6011000000000012,4111111111111111(VISA)`.

Please suggest , how to make this work ??Any suggestions

Comment: Check somewhere in `SDK` might be given fix digits for that so try to figure it out.

Comment: yes ,digits are fixed i.e.16

Comment: but if i change that validation and try to make transaction using 15 digit card number like 370000000000002 ,then my transaction result is null

Comment: So may be i suggest you to go with any other library like `PayPal`.

Comment: I have to use only this library

Comment: So try to `Modify` somewhere in `SDK` with min or max criteria for digits and check for null issues using debugger.

Comment: how can i check that why the transaction result is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109875/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-shivani-gupta).